# My Code Runs Better on my Old Macbook Pro than A New Surface Pro

Tags: java

I am currently developing a game completely in Java. As of now, my main loop is running in an Action Performed method that is updated by a timer every 100th of a second. In that loop, the code repaints and does a bunch of math for player position, enemy position(s), etc. My code runs perfectly normally and does not lag much on my mid 2009 macbook pro, and it weirdly enough runs awfully on my friends (very) new Surface Pro 4 (a clearly superior machine). It also runs really well on my (AMD) desktop PC. I ran some diagnostics and some samples with VisualVM and the task manager, and while it does not take up much of the machines resources, on the Surface Pro it runs at 4 or 5 FPS, mainly because of my paint component. My pain(t) component is huge, it contains tons of loops for particles in arraylists, enemies in arraylists, enemy particles in arraylists, etc. All of those need to be drawn. (They are deleted over time so that is not the issue). Why is my old macbook so much better at running this program than my friends new surface pro? Is there a better way to run the code? Github link here: https://github.com/gkgkgkgk/JetGame Thanks!
(Also, if you can, please test it on your computer and let me know how it runs!)

Here is my minimal, verifiable code:

```
public class Test extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
JFrame w;

Timer t = new Timer();


double elapsedTime = 0.016;

public Test() {
    w = new JFrame();
    w.setSize(1280, 720);
    w.setContentPane(this);
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    w.addKeyListener(this);
    w.setResizable(false);
    w.setVisible(true);
    loop();

}

public void loop() {
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            //does calculations
            repaint();

        }
    }, 0, 16);
}





public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //booleans are set to true and falso for movement in these methods

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {



}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}




public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; // Create a Java2D version of g.
    //painting is done in a bunch of nested for loops here

}

void calculateFPS(long x) {
    System.out.println(1000 / (System.currentTimeMillis() - x) + "FPS");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you compared JVM versions and settings?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DanielCentore I will provide one ASAP!

Comment: My wild guess is there is something wrong with your game loop (i.e. your game runs at different speeds on different machines).

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz I dont think it is. I switched from a swing timer to a util timer, and it is a solid 60 FPS on my windows desktop and macbook. But on some windows laptops its very unstable and laggy.... the schedule at fixed rate isnt perfectly accurate, but again, its inaccuracy is not as noticeable as it is in my code. (15-20 FPS difference with spikes)

Comment: @PM77-1 I will ASAP and I will let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try creating your own game loop, without relying on the util Timer.

There are dozens of examples online on how to write a working one.

1. http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0
2. https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/wiki/Game-loops (this tutorial is for LWJGL but I really like it)
3. https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/content/chapter2/chapter2.html (this is also LWJGL, but the algorithm should be the same)